# Is it possible, to make places in Mathematica notebooks accessible from a LibreOffice odt-document?

Tags: documentation, hyperlink

I want to document some findings which I have made using Mathematica (Version 12.3). But it is easier for me to do it in a LibreOfficeWriter (LO Writer) odt-document than in a Mathematica notebook.

LO Writer editing is easier than Notebook editing: less editing quirks (like introduction of unwanted spaces and the like or strange line breaking. LO Writer has a Navigator and other tools to easily mange chapters including subchapters "at large", e.g. arrange them differently, promote or demote the hierarchy of chapters with subchapters and the like. The most important advantage of LO Writer with respect to Mathematica Notebooks is, that LO Writer can open several views onto one and the same document. I use this feature frequently to have one view for my main working place, another one for a secondary working place and a third one just to search for things using the search function or the Navigator. If I encounter any error, I can repair it on the fly in any of the open views: they all act on the same document.

(Of course, Notebooks can collapse whole hierarchies of chapters - this is a feature which I miss in LO Writer!)

I do not loose the focus each time I have to look at another place, as it is when I work in a Mathematica notebook.

I want to unambiguously "point" from my documentation in an  odt file to defined places in existing notebooks. Preferably they should act like ordinary hyperlinks. How do I define the target bookmarks in my Mathematica notebook? How do I refer to them from LO Writer (probably like `file:///<path and filename>.nb#<target_designstion>`

Comment: Workbench has a similar concept: ["Notebook Links"](https://reference.wolfram.com/workbench/index.jsp?topic=/com.wolfram.eclipse.help/html/tasks/notebook/hyperlink.html) which can jump top a specific cell:

Answer (score 1):

I think deep-linking to a Mathematica notebook is impossible because implementation would be frustratingly different between different operating systems and is needed by only a tiny fraction of customers.

That leaves you with two options:

1. Learn to live with the limitations of the Mathematica notebook editor and edit your work there, or
2. Implement some hacks to simplify your workflow.

For (2), you can implement a simple navigation palette with two buttons - "locate" and "navigate":

- "locate" would attach a [unique tag](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellTags.html) to the current cell and copy it to the clipboard
- "navigate" would read a tag from the clipboard and navigate to it with `NotebookLocate`.

So your workflow would look something like this:

1. Locate a place you would want to link to. Press the "locate" button
2. Go to LO Writer, paste that unique tag where appropriate
3. When you are in LO Writer and want to navigate back to Mathematica, copy the required tag, switch to the Mathematica window, and press the "navigate" button on your palette. Yes, it's three actions instead of one, but probably not a big issue and requires the least amount of hacking.

**Update.** Or, if you want to completely avoid any additional programming, you can simply use the menu: Cell > Cell Tags > Add/Remove Cell Tags (command + J on Mac) to add new cell tags, and Cell > Cell Tags > Find Cell Tag to navigate between them.